# How to Add Multiple Products to Shopify Cart with One Button Click

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, shopify-api

Here is the button's code:

```
    {% assign p_annual = all_products[section.settings.paid_product_annual] %}
    {% assign p_free = all_products[section.settings.free_product] %}

        {% if section.settings.productlink1label != blank %}
            <button class="btn"
                 type="submit" 
                 name="paid-plan" 
                 id="paid-plan-option-annual" 
                 data-variant-id="{{ p_annual.selected_or_first_available_variant.metafields.subscriptions.discount_variant_id }}" 
                 data-variant-interval-value="{{ p_annual.metafields.subscriptions.shipping_interval_frequency }}" 
                 data-variant-interval-unit="{{ p_annual.metafields.subscriptions.shipping_interval_unit_type }}"
                 data-quickadd-id="{{ p_annual.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}"
                 data-quickadd-properties
             >
                        {{ p_annual.selected_or_first_available_variant.price | money_without_trailing_zeros }}{{ section.settings.productlink1label }}
             </button>
        {% endif %}
```

The code grabs the item by the ID and makes an AJAX request.

```
// quick add
    _document.on('click', '[data-quickadd-id]', function() {
        let _this = $(this);

        loadingBarTrigger('start');

        itemAdd(
            _this.attr('data-quickadd-id'), 
            _this.attr('data-quickadd-properties'), 
            (_this.attr('data-quickadd-quantity'))
                ? _this.attr('data-quickadd-quantity')
                : 1, 
            (!html.is('#cart')) ? true : false,
            (html.is('#cart')) ? true : false
        );
    });
```

*inside of cart function:*

```
onst itemAdd = (variantId, properties, qty, openCart, reloadPage) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: `/cart/add.js`,
            data: 
                {
                    id: variantId,
                    quantity: qty,
                    properties: (properties) 
                        ? JSON.parse(properties) : null
                },
                
            error: function(data) {
                console.error(data);

                loadingBarTrigger('done');
            },
            success: function() {
                loadingBarTrigger('move');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/cart',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    error: function(data) {
                        console.error(data);

                        loadingBarTrigger('done');
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        let minicartContent = $('#minicart-content');
                        let cartItemsHtml = $(data).find('#cart-content #cart-items').html();

                        // insert or prepend cart HTML
                        (minicartContent.find('#cart-items').length)
                            ? minicartContent.find('#cart-items').html(cartItemsHtml)
                            : minicartContent.prepend(cartItemsHtml);

                        // remove giftbox content if exists
                        (minicartContent.find('#cart-giftbox .item-info').length)
                            ? minicartContent.find('#cart-giftbox .item-info').remove()
                            : '';

                        loadingBarTrigger('done');
                        cartTotalUpdate();

                        // open cart
                        (openCart && !html.is('#cart'))
                            ? minicartTrigger.trigger('click') : '';

                        (reloadPage)
                            ? location.reload() : '';
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I know this is possible with the AJAX API update last year. But I'm unsure how to implement it in my store. The data-variant-id only accepts one value if I'm not mistaken. And what's data-variant-id comes first gets precedence. I guess the main thing is that I'm unsure how to send json with the submit button.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the best way is clearly answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72915384/17860991

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to check and default Shopify documentation and make changes to the code according to the documentation.
Here into documentation they clearly mentioned how you can add multiple product using AJAX API.

https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart
[image]

So you can check and update the code and past the multiple variants to items array like this demo code.

```
jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
  items: [
    {
      quantity: quantity,
      id: 1st ID
    },
    {
      quantity: quantity,
      id: 2nd ID
    },
    {
      quantity: quantity,
      id: 3rd ID
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that. I think my question was more about how to get an array to that point where I can run it through a for loop. And I think that's probably on my html side. Right now I only have a submit button with the data on it. Would a form with two pre-selected selects with the data on them be what I want to do instead?

Comment: Alright I figured that part out but now it's returned inconsistently. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025545/shopify-cart-ajax-request-returning-inconsistently

Answer (score 5):

In a classic add product form, you can replace:
`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}" disabled>` with:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="items[0][quantity]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="items[0][id]" value="ID_OF_YOUR_FIRST_PRODUCT_VARIANT">
<input type="hidden" name="items[1][quantity]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="items[1][id]" value="ID_OF_YOUR_SECOND_PRODUCT_VARIANT">
```

If you want to add the products in ajax, you just have to use the "FormData" object in the body of the request:

```javascript
let addToCartForm = document.querySelector('form[action$="/cart/add"]');
let formData = new FormData(addToCartForm);
fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/add.js', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
})
.then(response => {
  return response.json();
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Comment: Does anyone know if the name="items[0][quantity]" approach is documented somewhere?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but that's how HTML forms work in general when you want to have several values for the same field (here "items").